# is it possible to use XMLHTTP request to bind asp.net server controls

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, xmlhttprequest

i only found websites that uses the XMLHTTP request to call an aspx page or what ever page ( make a request to a page that appears the piece of data in a div or so )

but i have a question

is it possible to use it to bind  asp.net server controls

Examples
1- bind a gridview or datalist from this XMLHTTP request 
2- after click an edit button in a grid can i use  XMLHTTP request to fill some text boxes and dropdowns and other asp.net server controls 
3- can i use upload files using  XMLHTTP request

i want to know if this is possible or not because Ajax and update panels are very slow and affect the server and client performance

is there another alternative if my senarios are imposible with  XMLHTTP request 
where can i learn about this alternative

if this possible  where can i learn more about this 
 XMLHTTP request with asp.net server side controls 
instead of ajax and updatepanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider scrapping the ASP.NET server-side approach with XHR type implementation, and focus on the rendering on the client, if you are looking for pure AJAX performance.  This is the best and most peformant way, but requires more coding.  .NET 4 has a lot of nice improvements, and IMHO, JQuery is a must.

Comment: i dont understand what you a saying - do u mean that i can use the XHR witin my aspx page to achieve some mentioned above senarios from any basic asp.net web application - also is these improved in .net 4.0 where i can use without mush coding - one more thing what about JQUERY u mentioned how can i use it with asp.net - is there any tuturial or at least examples (by the way - what s "IMHO")